# Cisco ISE API POST (500 Error)

Tags: api

I am having difficulty creating a new endpoint in Cisco ISE using their API.  Here is my code:

```
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

# LAB Endpoint
API_ENDPOINT ="myurl.com:9060/ers/config/endpoint"
data= {
  "ERSEndPoint" : {
  "name": "name",
  "description": "description",
  "mac" : "99:99:99:99:99:99",
  "profileId" : "profileId",
  "staticProfileAssignment" : "false",
  "groupId" : "groupId",
  "staticGroupAssignment" : "false",
  "portalUser" : "portalUser",
  "identityStore" : "identityStore",
  "identityStoreId" : "identityStoreId",
  "customAttributes" : {
    "customAttributes" : {
      "key1" : "value1",
      "key2" : "value2"
      }
    }
  }
}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Accept': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = json.dumps(data), headers=headers, auth=('user', 'pwd'))
print r.text
```

I keep receiving a 500 error.

```
> {   "ERSResponse" : {
>     "operation" : "POST-create-endpoint",
>     "messages" : [ {
>       "title" : "CREATE: DB internal error during CRUD operation Unable to create the endpoint. ORA-02291: integrity constraint
> (CEPM.REF_ROLE_MASTER) violated - parent key not found\n",
>       "type" : "ERROR",
>       "code" : "CRUD operation exception"
>     } ],
>     "link" : {
>       "rel" : "related",
>       "href" : "https://ezlrtvise22.msstore.microsoftstore.com:9060/ers/config/endpoint",
>       "type" : "application/xml"
>     }   } }
```

It seems like it keeps throwing some weird Oracle DB key error.  Any suggestions?  I have tried using a REST Firefox extension to test as well and I still get the same error.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The value for groupId and profileID need to be the respective uuids of the group/profile you want to put this device in.  (Or you can leave out the profileID key entirely since it's not required.)

See https://example.com:9060/ers/config/endpointgroup to list all the endpoint groups (with their UUIDs).